# My query returns null in php but in mysql workbench it does return a value

Tags: php, mysqli, param

Also if i don't use 'die' in the code i will be redirected after a few seconds to  "unavailable page".

This is my code:

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'send')){
   $con2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mafioso') or die("error");
   $sender = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'sender');
   $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'subject');
   $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'message');
   if(strlen($message) > 5){
        $stmtCheckSender = $con2 -> prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `username` = ? ");
        $stmtCheckSender -> bind_param('s', $sender);
        $stmtCheckSender -> execute();
        $stmtCheckSender -> bind_result($getSender2);
        if($getSender2 == NULL){
                var_dump($getSender2); die;
                $message2 = "The user to who you want to send the message doesn't exist.";
             }else{ 
            while($stmtCheckSender -> fetch()){
                 $senderExists = $getSender2;
                 break;
            }
             $stmtCheckSender -> close();

            $stmtSendMessage = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_messages`(`idreceiver`, `subject`, `message`, `idsender`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmtSendMessage -> bind_param('issi', $senderExists, $subject, $message, $_SESSION['userID']);
            $stmtSendMessage -> execute();
       }
   }else{
       $message2 = "The message is too short!";
   }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: This `$stmtSendMessage = $con -> prepare` should be `$stmtSendMessage = $con2 -> prepare` --- *right?* Since you're using it already in another query, or is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks that i didn't see that but it didn't solve my problem, it looks like it doesn't execute bind_param ..

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so, see if that yields anything. I noticed you're using sessions, `session_start();` in your files?

Comment: i pasted it on top of my file but doesn't do anything.. Pff very frustrating :( And yess i have my sessions started

Comment: You will need to to look at your error logs or display errors.

Comment: it doesn't log anything i see old errors but not a new 1

Comment: i got an error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mafioso\php\PHPmessage.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mafioso\php\PHPmessage.php(22): mysqli->prepare('SELECT `id` FRO...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mafioso\message.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mafioso\php\PHPmessage.php on line 22"